# @ is converted into %40 at server side

Tags: android, encoding, urlencode, encode

I'm trying to send post request to web service which have an email and password. When I add special character @ in parameter (i.e qadir.suh@gmail.com) it is converted to %40. I have checked server side, they are getting %40 instead of @.

Here is my code:

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                                    "http://www.myurl.com/requesthandler.ashx");
                            // from list to arraylist
                            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                                    3);
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtUserId",
                                    "qadir.suh@gmail.com"));
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtPassword",
                                    "blahblah"));
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "login"));
try {
                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                                nameValuePairs));

                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    HttpResponse response = null;
                    try {
                        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i("Client Protocol Excption", e + "");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i("IO Exception", e + "");
                    }
                    String responseText = null;
                    try {
                        responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response
                                .getEntity());
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i("Parse Exception", e + "");

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i("IO Exception 2", e + "");

                    }
                    String afterDecode = null;

                    try {
                        afterDecode = URLDecoder.decode(responseText, "UTF-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, afterDecode,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I know that

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                            nameValuePairs));
```

This encodes the URL in UTF-8. So how can I achieve my goal so that the server should receive the @ symbol instead of the %40? Or is there any method to POST the request without using `setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs))`? Or is there any method so that we can send the decoded version of POST request?

Comment: Add a code on the server side that will decode the post params.

Comment: why should we do so sir..! I m an android developer. Basically i hav not developed the webservices. i hv just provided a url, I dont hv opportunity to change the webservice.

Comment: The problem is on the server.  This is normal URL encoding. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: one thing more i want to tell is that I tested this on Iphone. and also from a ASP.net form, its working fine.

Comment: URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set only.Any character outside this set will be converted to the ASCII format, so that it can be set over http. You can't send it as it is. You will have to add a url decoding code at the server's end.

Comment: thanks for comments but still i m little confused and getting the same %40 instead of @ symbol.. why its making problm with android only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posting URL-encoded form parameters, but probably not setting the content-type to **"x-www-form-urlencoded"**. This is needed so that the server will know how to interpret the posted parameters. Try adding this line before calling `httppost.setEntity()`:

```
httppost.addHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

**EDIT: If you don't want to use the URL-encoding, you can simply post a string**

If you don't want to URL-encode the POST body, you can do this instead:

```
// Create post body as name/value pairs in form format
String postBody = "txtUserId=qadir.suh@gmail.com&txtPassword=blahblah&type=login";
try {
    httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(postBody));
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer David. I also tried this but still server is getting the %40 instead of @ symbol. whats wrong with that..:(

Comment: Yes, you will always get the %40 instead of "@" because you are creating an URL-encoded POST body. However, with the correct header, the server will be able to properly convert %40 into "@". If possible, see if you can find out the complete content of the POST request that is sent to the server. You want to see all of the HTTP headers.

Comment: ok you r trying to say that its not of my headache to decode the first and then send to the server side.. ??

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that your server should be able to decode this if you send it properly. I've just edited my answer to show you another way to do this without using URL-encoding. This will work, but only if the POST data doesn't contain any characters that are illegal in URL-encoded forms (like "&" or "=")

Comment: This worked David.. Thank u so much for your such co-operation. I want to ask one thing that is there any disadvantage of POSTING request to server as u did with out encoding? (i.e String postBody = "txtUserId=qadir.suh@gmail.com&txtPassword=blahblah&type=login";
try {
    httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(postBody));
} )

Comment: As I already said: the only disadvantage is that you cannot include certain special characters (including 8-bit characters (accents, umlauts, etc) in the post data if you don't URL-encode it. If you know that your data doesn't contain these special characters, then you are fine. If, however, the user is allowed to enter whatever he wants and you then send this data to the server, then you need to either URL-encode the data appropriately OR you need to prevent the user from entering certain special characters.